# Draw a quiver diagram with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to know how to draw a quiver diagram like this one. I know there exists TikZ or something like that, but I don't know the commands or packages necessary to draw it.

[image: QUIVER DIAGRAM]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you want the arrows close to the nodes I think that you need to use a decoration. Here is one way to do it:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{% arrow close to the source: the 0.2 determines where the arrow is drawn
  ->-/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.2 with {\arrow{stealth}}},
              postaction={decorate}},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw},thick]
  \node(NL) at (0,0){$N$};
  \node(NR) at (2,0){$N$};
  \draw[->-](NL.north east)--(NR.north west);
  \draw[->-](NR.south west)--(NL.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can set `outer sep=0`  of the nodes for better merging.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have an extra question... In your code (that works), how can I enlarge the circles... I mean, the whole figure?.

Comment: @user133596 Adding `scale=3` to the tikzpicture environment (that is,  `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, every node...]') will make the picture three times larger. Adding `minimum size` to the node specifications will make the nodes bigger (so `every node/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=16mm}` or `\node[minimum size=20mm](NR)...`).

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat similar PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\quiver[#1,#2]#3#4{
\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(\fpeval{2*#1+#2},\fpeval{2*#1})
    \rput(#1,#1){#3}
    \rput(\fpeval{#1+#2},#1){#4}
    \cnode(#1,#1){#1}{A}
    \cnode(\fpeval{#1+#2},#1){#1}{B}
   \psset{
     offset = -8pt,
     nodesep = -3pt, % adjust manually
     ArrowInside = ->,
     ArrowInsidePos = 0.25,
     arrowsize = 0.2
   }
    \ncline{A}{B}
    \ncline{B}{A}
  \end{pspicture}
 \caption{A quiver diagram between #1 and #2.} % I have no idea if it's called that...
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

% \quiver[<radius>, <separation>]{<left node>}{<right node>}
\quiver[0.5, 3.5]{$N$}{$M$}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is choose the radius of the circles and the distance between them, and choose what to write in the circles (as the arguments to the `\quiver` command).

Answer (score 4):

An answer using TikZ version 3:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{:}{:}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ->-/.style={arrows={:Stealth[reversed,sep=1.5ex]-}},
    every node/.style={circle,draw,outer sep=0},
    thick
  ]
  \node(NL) at (0,0){$N$};
  \node(NR) at (2,0){$N$};
  \draw[->-](NR.north west)--(NL.north east);
  \draw[->-](NL.south east)--(NR.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The line `\pgfarrowsdeclare{:}{:}{}{}` is used to create a "no-tip" arrow spec (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207630/36686)).
Then the special arrows are generated using `arrows={:Stealth[reversed,sep=1.5ex]-}` which reads as

> put no tip, then a reversed Stealth tip separated by 1.5ex space from the previous and then complete the arrow with a line to destination

This style is then aliased to `->-` for better readability and reusability, similarly to @Andrew's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The "or something like that" in the OP includes [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it), the Knuth-Hobby drawing language.  Here's my attempt at your quiver diagram.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

-z1 = z2 = 40 right;

path c[]; 
c1 = fullcircle scaled 20 shifted z1; 
c2 = fullcircle scaled 20 shifted z2; 

draw c1; draw c2; 
label(btex $N$ etex, z1); 
label(btex $N$ etex, z2); 

path a[]; 
s = 2/3; % 8 points in a "fullcircle" so 2/3 == 30°
a1 = point 0-s of c1 -- point 4+s of c2;
a2 = point 4-s of c2 -- point 0+s of c1;

r = 1/5;
drawarrow subpath(0,r) of a1; draw subpath (r,1) of a1;
drawarrow subpath(0,r) of a2; draw subpath (r,1) of a2;

endfig;
end.
```

Answer (score 3):

Another PSTricks one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\newcommand*\quiver[3][2cm]{%
  \cnodeput(0,0){A}{\strut#2}\cnodeput(#1,0){B}{\strut#3}%
  \ncline[offset=-1ex,nodesep=-1pt,ArrowInside=->,ArrowInsidePos=0.3,arrowsize=0.2]{A}{B}%
  \ncline[offset=-1ex,nodesep=-1pt,ArrowInside=->,ArrowInsidePos=0.3,arrowsize=0.2]{B}{A}%
  \hspace{#1}}

\begin{document}

\quiver{$N$}{$n$} \par\bigskip
\quiver[3cm]{$N$}{$n$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A short solution with `\pstricks-add`. The `nodesep` parameter has been adjusted manually:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\[ \psset{ArrowInside=->, ArrowInsidePos=0.25, arrowinset=0.25 , linewidth=0.6pt, nodesep=-1.5pt, colsep=1.2cm, offset=1ex}
\begin{psmatrix}[mnode = circle]
N & N
%%%
 \ncline{1,1}{1,2}\ncline{1,2}{1,1}
\end{psmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the `pdf` option do for `article` in this case exactly? Does it load some package?

Comment: @skpblack: it allows for compiling directly with `pdflatex`, provided you use the `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX) switch, or `--enable-write18`(MiKTeX). It tells pstricks to load the `auto-pst-pdf` package, whch does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun with TikZ.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2,0) circle (12pt) (2,0) circle (12pt);
    \draw[->] (60:12pt)++(-2,0) -- +(1,0);
    \draw (60:12pt) ++(-1,0) ++ (-2pt,0) -- ($(120:12pt)+(2,0)$); 
    \draw[->] (-120:12pt) ++(2,0) -- +(-1,0);
    \draw (-120:12pt) ++(1,0) ++ (2pt,0) -- ($(-60:12pt)+(-2,0)$); 
    \node at (-2,0) {A};
    \node at (2,0) {B}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]