# TikZ3 arrow tip specification for "no arrow" or "shift tip" option

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

A specification like this

```
arrows={|>[sep=10pt]-}
```

works perfectly giving something like `|-->--------`.

I would like to use the `sep` option to shift the arrow in the same way but without the need for an arrow tip at the beginning.
If I write

```
arrows={>[sep=10pt]-}
```

I obtain a shifted arrow tip but the line supporting it **starts with the arrow tip**. Adding `.` at the beginning does not help.

The question is: is there an arrow tip name indicating "no tip"?
If such tip name existed I could use it to mark the start of the arrow line.

Alternatively: is there a better way to shift the arrow tip *using tip specifications*?

*Related*:

- by [defining a new arrow tip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82581/36686) you can control the extent of the tip.
- by drawing the arrow in two steps you can draw a `->` arrow `10pt` long and then the rest; very unsatisfactory.
- by using decorations one can position items, including an arrow tip, in any position. I would prefer to have an arrow tip specification.

Given TikZ 3 offer such powerful ways to modify the style of the tip (color, scale, slant, line style, bending etc) the absence of a shifting option / null-tip feels like an important omission.

Comment: Can you try `arrows={->[sep=10pt]-}`?

Comment: @Jake I should have mentioned I tried that as well but `-` is not an arrow tip kind and TikZ would throw an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got it by defining my own "no-tip" arrow tip specification:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\pgfarrowsdeclare{:}{:}{}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style={circle,draw,outer sep=0},
  thick]
  \node(A) at (0,0){A};
  \node(B) at (2,0){B};
  \draw[arrows={:>[sep=10pt]-}](A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```